# How to change voice of speaker?

Tags: c#, text-to-speech

I trying to do something similar with [that](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/182881/Text-to-Speech) but its not changing the voice... How I can change it?

Answer (score 0):

if I understood you correctly, you should create a SpeechSynthesizer object:

```
SpeechSynthesizer voice = new SpeechSynthesizer();
```

Then you can use the method below to select a voice with specificvoice characteristics

```
voice.SelectVoiceByHints (VoiceGender, VoiceAge, Int32, CultureInfo)
```

Comment: I just have `voice.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Male)` that should  work too... Do i need to install the voices? I have only the female voice